# React: TypeScript: Set and Get Global Context with useReducer

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this route that has a login and logout button, the error in the browser is 'Property 'dispatch' does not exist on type '{}'.'

```
(home.tsx)

    import React, { useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
    import { Dispatch, Global } from '../components/context';
    import { LOG_IN, LOG_OUT} from '../components/reducer';

    const Home: React.FC = () => {
      const { global } = useContext(Global);
      const { dispatch } = useContext(Dispatch);

      const login = () => {
        dispatch({ type: LOG_IN});
      };

      const logout = () => {
        dispatch({ type: LOG_OUT});
      };
      return (
      <div>
        {global.loggedIn && <div>You are logged in</div>}
        {!global.loggedIn && <div>You are logged out</div>}
        <br/>
        <button onClick={login}>Log In</button>
        <button onClick={logout}>Log Out</button>
      </div>
      );
    };

    export { Home };
```

I think I have the context wrong

```
(context.tsx)

    import { createContext } from 'react';
    import { InitialState } from './reducer';

    const Dispatch = createContext({}); // <--- I'm missing somthing here??

    const Global = createContext({
      global: InitialState,
    });

    export { Dispatch, Global };
```

The reducer feels right

```
(reducer.tsx)

    const LOG_IN = 'LOG_IN';
    const LOG_OUT = 'LOG_OUT';

    interface StateInterface {
      loggedIn: boolean;
    }
    const InitialState: StateInterface = {
      loggedIn: true,
    };

    interface ActionInterface {
      type: string;
    }
    const Reducer = (state: StateInterface, action: ActionInterface) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOG_IN':
          return {
            ...state,
            loggedIn: true,
          };
        case 'LOG_OUT':
          return {
            ...state,
            loggedIn: false,
          };
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
    export { Reducer, InitialState, LOG_IN, LOG_OUT };
```

And the route I believe is right

```
(Router.tsx)

    import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
    import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { Dispatch, Global } from './components/context';
    import { Layout } from './components/layout';
    import { InitialState, Reducer } from './components/reducer';
    import { Home } from './routes/home';
    import { NotFound } from './routes/notFound';

    const Router: React.FC = () => {
      const [global, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, InitialState);
      return (
        <Dispatch.Provider value={{ dispatch }}>
          <Global.Provider value={{ global }}>
            <BrowserRouter>
              <Route
                render={({ location }) => (
                  <Layout location={location}>
                    <Switch location={location}>
                      <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                      <Route component={NotFound} />
                    </Switch>
                  </Layout>
                )}
              />
            </BrowserRouter>
          </Global.Provider>
        </Dispatch.Provider>
      );
    };

    export { Router };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set as initial value for the Context the properties that will later be used. Otherwise any Component that uses the Context, on the first render, will get undefined properties.

So either set some kind of value for the property that the Provider will fill later, or check in each Component that uses the Context if the property exists (not recommended).

```
import { Dispatch as ReactDispatch } from "react";

// We assign the same type the property is going to have later
const Dispatch = createContext<{ dispatch: ReactDispatch<ActionInterface> }>({
    dispatch: () => {}
});
```

Comment: Some progress I get a new error, at home.tsx when I do `dispatch({ type: LOG_IN});` I now get `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.ts(2554)`

Comment: @Bill, That is because the definition I used for the example isnt expecting anything. Let me give a deeper look into the logic you are using.

Comment: @Bill I edited the answer, I think it should now cover the use case.

Comment: That clearted one eror and made one more now in Router.tsx where we have `<Dispatch.Provider value={{ dispatch }}>` I now get the error `Type 'Dispatch<ActionInterface>' is not assignable to type '() => void'.ts(2322)
context.tsx(5, 3): The expected type comes from property 'dispatch' which is declared here on type '{ dispatch: () => void; }'`

Comment: Then its probably easier to simply use the type that dispatch has from the React types. Try to import `Dispatch` from react and use it as type: `import { Dispatch as ReactDispatch } from "react";` and then `const Dispatch = createContext({ dispatch: ReactDispatch });`

Comment: The answer now gives the error `'ReactDispatch' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)`

Comment: Failed to compile `Type 'Dispatch<ActionInterface>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<string>'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ActionInterface'.  TS2322`

Comment: in context.tsx I am importing Dispatch from "react" but not in Router.tsx, feels like we have too many things named Dispatch, notice the lowercase and Capitalised versions, the above error was coming from Router.tsx

Comment: I think the imported `Dispatch` type from `"react"` is the one used for the dispatch function that `useReducer` returns. As your context is called the same we have to rename the import.

Comment: Yes I see its renamed, after I add your solution I get an error in Router,tsx. the part that has the error is `<Dispatch.Provider value={{ dispatch }}>` and the error itself is `Type 'Dispatch<ActionInterface>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<string>'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ActionInterface'.ts(2322)
globalState.tsx(18, 34): The expected type comes from property 'dispatch' which is declared here on type '{ dispatch: Dispatch<string>; }'`

Comment: Now I get it, you defined `ActionInterface` as the action argument type in the reducer. Lets put the same type then: `...createContext<{ dispatch: ReactDispatch< ActionInterface> }>...`.